# python/django database connection issue

Tags: python, django

Database settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.environ.get('DB_ENGINE', "mysql"),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME', "django_db"),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER', "root"),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS', "123456798"),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST', "localhost"),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
```

error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Connecting with mysql to generate migration but facing issue
Its my first time and facing following above issue please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

`mysql` in `'ENGINE': os.environ.get('DB_ENGINE', "mysql"),`

Try this:

```
'ENGINE': os.environ.get('DB_ENGINE', "django.db.backends.mysql"),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '123456798',
    }
}
```

Try this to establish a connection.
I don't usually add HOST or Port but it still connect to database.
I only mention Host or Port if they don't have the default settings.